# Material-ui ToolbarTitle loses its font family

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, material-ui

[image]
On the tutorial page it says that it should look like the Options title above, which is clearly using the Roboto font.
However when I tried to use it, similarly as shown in the tutorial, mine does not use the Roboto font, even though I included it in project through a CDN and it actually works everywhere else except here.

[image]

Here you can see the way I'm using it:

```
<Toolbar >
  <ToolbarGroup firstChild={true}>
    <ToolbarTitle text="Options"/>
  </ToolbarGroup>
</Toolbar >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as I wrapped them into a Paper component, it started working properly.